# After performing Oracle to SQL Server Migration I lost my SysDB database. How can I recreate it?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, t-sql, migration

I recently did a Oracle to SQL Server 2008 R2 Migration. The PL/SQL stored procedures were converted to T/SQL by SSMA. The converted T/SQL has many references to the sysdb database, for instance `sysdb.ssma_oracle.db_check_init_package`
I then exported the SQL Server 2008 R2 database, and imported it to SQL Server 2012. However I forgot to copy the sysdb database. What is the easiest way of creating the sysdb database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install `SSMA for Oracle 5.2 Extension Pack.exe` (downloadable from Microsoft) on the computer with the SQL Server database (tell it to ignore the fact that Oracle is not installed on the computer) and it will create the sysdb database for you, and also the Extended Stored Procedures that it needs.